# Purple tint using Raspbmc / XBian / OpenELEC

Tags: raspbmc, hdmi, display, openelec, xbian

I installed Raspbmc and everything is working fine except for the purple tint. (Also happening in XBian)

The Raspberry Pi is connected to the tv via HDMI.
The HDMI cable works fine when connected to my PS3.
The RCA jack isn't working so I can't test with that.

Also, when Raspbmc is booting, the logo screen has a black background at the start but it turns purple near the end of the boot.

I took a video of it: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tYhnEPv-I44

Comment: Can you test on a different television? Make sure its not some preset there?

Comment: Unfortunately I only have one tv. I've gone through the settings on my tv but there was nothing that helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out...

I had to edit **/boot/config.txt** and add the following line:

```
hdmi_mode=5
```

I started by adding `hdmi_safe=1` and tweaked it from there.

Here's a link describing the settings in config.txt:
http://elinux.org/RPiconfig

---

***Fix for OpenELEC v3.2.4***
Add the following line to **/flash/config.txt**

```
hdmi_mode=5
```

---

***Fix for OpenELEC v4.0.7***

Make **/flash** writable using

```
mount /flash -o remount,rw
```

Add the following 2 lines to **/flash/config.txt**

```
hdmi_group=1
hdmi_mode=5
```

Comment: I just installed OpenELEC and it had the same problem. The fix is the same but the location of config.txt is different. It's located at **/flash/config.txt**

Comment: ... and it continues... I just upgraded OpenELEC v4.0.7 with the same problem. The config.txt file was still at **/flash/config.txt** but I had to make /flash writable using `mount /flash -o remount,rw`. I also had to add **hdmi_group=1**.